# Probability distribution of the number of clusters in a chinese restaurant process

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability distribution of the number of clusters in a chinese restaurant process with concentration parameter $\alpha$?

The description of CRP is given in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_restaurant_process. Chinese restaurant process is a distribution on all possible partitions of the integers 1 to n. The description also provides the exact distribution of the random partition. However, I was looking for the distribution on the number of clusters in a given random partition.

Comment: Can you give a description of the "chinese restaurant process"?

Comment: Just for fun: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrsH8KFzwxY

Answer (score 1):

The number of tables in CRP is not a distribution. Since the probability for the $n^{th}$ customer to sit on a new table is $$\frac{\alpha}{n-1+\alpha}$$ The number of new tables is $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\alpha}{n-1+\alpha}$$

While we know the harmonic series $H_n = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{N} $ could be bound: 
$$\ln(N) < H_n < 1 + \ln(N+1) $$

So asymptotically the number of tables is 
$$\alpha \log N$$